# Centering overlay in the screen even if the page is scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I wanted to create an overlay so I created a div called 'background' where in there is a div inside it called 'overlay-box', which is the one that will popup. So my problem is that since the page is scrollable, I want the popup to be in the center whether the screen's focus is in the bottom part or in the top part of the page.

```
.background {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1000; /* high z-index */
        background: #000; /* fallback */
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.overlay-box{
        background: #fff;
        padding: 1%;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        top: 15%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: 0 0 0 -20%; 
        cursor: default;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just set the position of `.background` to be fixed?

Comment: Agreed - [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QKeJ4/)

Comment: Or set the `overlay-box` position to `fixed` itself. http://jsfiddle.net/Y82yE/

Answer (score 0):

`.background {position:fixed}` change this in background.